# hot-reload traefik frontend rules in a file while using docker containers

Tags: docker, traefik

I would like to be able to hot-reload the frontend rules but using docker containers.

Can I get the traefik frontend rules defined in a file **AND** us the docker container names as a backends?

**Current docker config**: It works but it's hardcoded / can't be hot-reloaded

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 -v $PWD:/etc/traefik -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock traefik

docker run -d --name v1 -l "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/,/foo" emilevauge/whoami 

docker run -d --name v2 -l "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix: /bar" emilevauge/whoami
```

`/` and `/foo` go to container v1; `/bar` go to v2. Great.

The challenge is to hot-reload the front end rules. Example: I want "bar" to be on v1 now.

My idea was to switch to a "file" configuration (because files changes are watched and therefore can be hot-reloaded)

But I'm stuck in configuring the backends. Can I use a container name there ?

Here is what I tried:

- adding backend label to container `docker run -d --name v1 -l "traefik.backend=v1" emilevauge/whoami`
- Adding this `rules.toml` file (the one that hot reloads!)

```
[frontends]
    [frontends.v1]
        backend = "backend-v1"
        [frontends.v1.routes.test]
        rule = "PathPrefix: /,/foo"
    [frontends.v2]
        backend = "backend-v2"
        [frontends.v2.routes.test]
        rule = "PathPrefix: /bar"
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. It looks like i need to declare backends in the file too.

How can I declare my backend to existing containers ?

```
[backends]
    [backends.v1]
        --> here something to reference container v1
    [backends.v2]
        --> here something to reference container v2
```

is that possible at all? Or am I just doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: I am curious about this as well, mainly because I want an option to add new domains added , directed at the app on a daily basis to be given a Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate on the fly. You can hot reload a File file https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/file/#one-separate-file , but not sure if that would work well with `[acme_domains]`

Answer (score 0):

> Current docker config: It works but it's hardcoded / can't be hot-reloaded

You might need to destroy the container and run it up again from scratch.

**Containers are labeled only once during creation.**

> Adding this rules.toml file (the one that hot reloads!)

Did you explicitly enable file watch?

```yaml
providers:
  file:
    directory: /path/to/dynamic/conf
    watch: true
```

@see: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/file/